# ng2-completer does not return any search results while searching on an array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-completer

I am trying to use ng2-completer for auto-completing in a search box and it does not work except for an array of strings.
I get 'No Results found'. From the screenshot it can be seen that "name" has been loaded into the array.

I want to use [ng2-completer](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer) to search on an array of (say) Person.

But need to search on name and address and so I cannot just use a string[].

Tried a number of approaches: both with Remote Data and also with Local but both fail when using a class.
I have tried a simple version on the classic Angular Tour of Heroes [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5).
Here are my changes.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CompleterService, CompleterData } from 'ng2-completer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  protected searchStr: string;
  protected dataService: CompleterData;
  searchData: Array<Person> = [];
  constructor(private completerService: CompleterService) {
    this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name', 'person');
    for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
      let p = new Person(
        i, 
        "name" + i,
        "address" + i,
        1000);
      this.searchData.push(p);
      console.log("person["+i+"] :" + p.id + " " + p.name + " " + p.address);
    }
  }

}

export class Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  income: number;
  constructor(id:number, name:string, address:string, income:number) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.income = income;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
  <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
</nav>
<h1>Search person</h1>
            <ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [datasource]="dataService" [minSearchLength]="0"></ng2-completer>
            <h1>Search captain</h1>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid rgb(255, 255, 0);">This is app component!</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-messages></app-messages>
```

failed

[image: screen shot showing failed]

Comment: Is it possible for you to create stackblitz ?

Comment: Can you please copy paste my code into the stack blitz tutorial for this?

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using titleField in the wrong way. According to the documents it's the field which will be displayed as search result from your input data.

Try this

```
this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name', 'name');
```

or

```
this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name', 'address');
```

Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lqxbhf)